# Adding duplicate tiles from different arrays PIXI.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, pixi.js

I'm trying to create a slot game;
I have some images that I put into an array

```
var createSlots = function(){
  //setup images as tilingSprites
 var slot1 = new PIXI.extras.TilingSprite(t1, 200, 200);
 var slot2 = new PIXI.extras.TilingSprite(t2, 200, 200);
 var slot3 = new PIXI.extras.TilingSprite(t3, 200, 200);
 var slot4 = new PIXI.extras.TilingSprite(t4, 200, 200);
 var slot5 = new PIXI.extras.TilingSprite(t5, 200, 200);
 var slot6 = new PIXI.extras.TilingSprite(t6, 200, 200);
 var slot7 = new PIXI.extras.TilingSprite(t7, 200, 200);
 var slot8 = new PIXI.extras.TilingSprite(t8, 200, 200);
 var slot9 = new PIXI.extras.TilingSprite(t9, 200, 200);    
 var slot10 = new PIXI.extras.TilingSprite(t10, 200, 200);

//push slots into array; images, sprites etc.
        mainSlotArr.push(slot1, slot2, slot3, slot4, slot5, slot6, slot7, slot8, slot9, slot10); 

};
```

for the moment I have 2 functions (will combine them once I get this working)

createReels1 and createReels2

what they do is copy the mainSlotArray use a shuffle function
Then populate to 2 columns (reels) each (at the moment createReels2 only does one reel)
it then removes the array element from the array it's using

The trouble I'm having is that whatever image tiles are used in createReels2, disappear if they are being used in createReels1 function, e.g if image1.png used in createReels2 and createReels1, then it is not visible in the first 2 reels

createReels functions below (alot of hard coding!)

```
var createReels1 = function(){
     slotArr1 = mainSlotArr.slice();
     shuffle(slotArr1);
     var counter = 0;
     var num = 0
 for(var i = 0; i <2; i++){
     var slotContainer = new PIXI.Container();
     slotContainer.width = 100;
     slotContainer.height = 400;
     slotContainer.y = 100;
     slotContainer.x = i*130;
     stage.addChild(slotContainer);
    slotContainerArr.push(slotContainer);
     for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++){
         var slot = slotArr1[j];

         var toDel = slotArr1.indexOf(slot);
             slot.scale.y = slot.scale.x = .5;
             console.log(slot);
         var nextY = j*(slot.height/2);
            slot.y = nextY;
            slotContainerArr[i].addChild(slot);
            slotArr1.splice(toDel, 1);//remove from array  

      }

   }

 }


var createReels2 = function(){
     slotArr2 = mainSlotArr.slice();

     shuffle(slotArr2);
    var counter = 0;
     var num = 0
 for(var i = 0; i <1; i++){
     var slotContainer = new PIXI.Container();
     slotContainer.width = 100;
     slotContainer.height = 400;
     slotContainer.y = 100;
     slotContainer.x = 260;
     stage.addChild(slotContainer);
     slotContainerArr.push(slotContainer);
     for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++){
         var slot = slotArr2[j];
         var toDel = slotArr2.indexOf(slot);
             slot.scale.y = slot.scale.x = .5;

         var nextY = j*(slot.height/2);
            slot.y = nextY;
       slotContainerArr[2].addChild(slot);
        slotArr2.splice(toDel, 1);//remove from array
      }

   }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the code correctly, with quick check:

Sprites can have only one parent. If you check the Sprite object, it actually has a parent property. So slotArr1 and slotArr2 have identical Sprites and that fact doesn't change id you slice them. Then when you are assigning them to different containers, they get moved from one container to the other. You can reuse textures sure, but one Sprite can only have on parent.